# Find phone number in string - regular

Tags: regex

I need to find phone number in nsstring without white spaces.
I use regular: `^\\+[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3,14}$`.
It works when i have string with phone number only - `345908233`.
But when i have a string - `sdkaflfnsdfhgiusafusfbuosb345908233fkjsadfnksjfnas` it doesn't work.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Note that `[1-9]{1}` is the same as `[1-9]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `^` and `$` form your regex. `\+[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3,14}`